# Cannot get play-mailer gives cannot find symbol

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

When trying to use the player-mailer plugin I get the following error while compiling:

```
[error] /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/Y2kBooking/app/logic/support/Mails.java:4: package play.libs.mailer does not exist
[error] play.libs.mailer.Email
[error] /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/Y2kBooking/app/logic/support/Mails.java:5: package play.libs.mailer does not exist
[error] play.libs.mailer.MailerClient
[error] /Users/Luuk/Documents/Java/Y2kBooking/app/logic/support/Mails.java:14: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class MailerClient
[error]   location: class logic.support.Mails
[error] MailerClient

app/logic/support/Mails.java:24: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class Email
[error]   location: class logic.support.Mails
```

This is my mailer:

```
package logic.support;

import play.Configuration;
import play.libs.mailer.Email;
import play.libs.mailer.MailerClient;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Mails {
    @Inject
    MailerClient mailerClient;

    public void sendLoggerEmail(String message, Exception e) {
        String fullMessage = "The following error occured:\n" + message;

        if (e != null) {
            fullMessage += "\n\n" + "Error message:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n\nStacktrace\n" + org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
        }

        Email email = new Email();
        email.setSubject("Booking application warning");
        email.setFrom("Booking system FROM <" + Configuration.root().getString("adminEmail") + ">");
        email.addTo("Webmaster TO <" + Configuration.root().getString("adminEmail") + ">");
        email.setBodyText(fullMessage);
        mailerClient.send(email);
    }

}
```

In build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( javaJdbc , cache , javaWs , evolutions , "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18", "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % "test", "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1")
```

I did clean the project and rebuild, but always the same. I am using Play (Java) 2.4.4

[Edit:]
The jar is present, and IDEA has no problem with it, so it seems that it is just not available at runtime.

[Edit2:]
The problem seems only when Debugging with IDEA. Running from the terminal with activator works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was a problem with the debugging session of IDEA.
Restarting everything solved the problem.